# Wrong figure folder when using \graphicspath

Tags: graphics, miktex2.9

I want to include a figure `example.pdf`, contained in the folder `figs` in the same folder that my `main.tex`. The content of `main.tex` is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./figs/}}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{example.pdf} %%

\end{document}
```

However, the resulting pdf contains `example.pdf` from the folder `c:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\alertmessage\`, and not `example.pdf` from the folder figs on my main-file folder. It was just a happy coincidence that I had not the package `alertmessage` installed and MiKTeX stopped the compilation process suggesting to install it. Otherwise, I would have had a tough time trying to find where the unknown "figure" was coming from.

A similar thing occurs with any pdf named as one of the many pdf files contained in the subfolders in `..\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\`.

I am using MiKTeX 2.9.7300 (64-bit) on Windows 7 (64-bit). The `graphicx` package is version v1.2a (2019/11/30).

Is that the intended behaviour of LaTeX and `\includegraphics` with `\graphicspath`? Or is that a bug in MiKTeX or perhaps `graphicx`?

Comment: try with `\includegraphics{./example.pdf}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If you include it as an answer, I'd be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\includegraphics` searches for graphics first with `kpsewhich` (which looks first in the current folder and then into the texmf trees) and after this tries the pathes in `\graphicspath`. To force it to use a local file, prepend the name with `./`. This works for graphics in subfolders too. So for example this here

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{chapters/}}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\includegraphics{./example-image}
\includegraphics{./sub}
\includegraphics{./chapters/sub}
\end{document}
```

will input (assuming that the chapters folders contains the images example-image.pdf and sub.pdf, while the current folder has a sub.pdf too)

```
<c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image.pdf> 
<./chapters//./example-image.pdf>
<sub.pdf>
<./chapters/sub.pdf>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.